# Union three rasters using raster calculator of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I want to combine 3 rasters (land use, water bodies and airports) into on raster with only two values 0 and 1 where the places of land use, wetlands and airports are = 0, otherwise = 1
I used raster calculator with a simple expression using boolean OR |
but I get an output raster with a scale from 0 to 255 and it's not appearing on the map.
`"landUse" | "waterBodies" |  "airports_"` I'm trying to create a constraint map where these places are not suitable and others are suitable.

[image]

Edit:
These are the values of the three rasters

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to give more detail in your question. What are the values in your 3 input rasters and show how you are running the calculator tool.

Comment: Regarding the calculator tool, I used the same expression above and then pressed Run (added a picture of it)

Comment: The layers are feature classes but I converted them to rasters

Answer (score 0):

I created 3 polygon layers and faked some overlapping data with various classes. I then converted these to raster datasets (stored in file geodatabase) and used the class field as the value field in the polygon to raster tool. This created the 3 rasters, they all came out as 4-bit rasters.

Inputs

[image: Rasters]

I ran the Raster calculator exactly as you did and I get the expected result (black pixels):

[image: Results]

So the workflow worked for me so I can only deduce something is odd about your input rasters?